# rendering the copy of the field on the button click

Tags: jquery, flask-wtforms

I've got the field that I would like to multiply on the click of the button. I don't even know where to start?

My only code so far. fieldDef is a field definition originally rendered by wtforms:

```
    this.fieldDef = params.fieldDef
    var that = $('#' + this.fieldDef["name"]);

    this.init = function() {
       that.after('<input id="addBtn" type="button" value="Add another"/>')
       $("#addBtn").click(function(){
         //this.fieldDef.render()??
       })
     }
     this.init()
```

Could you please point me to some resource with ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you explain a bit more what your idea is with example?

From what I understood it looks to me that clone is exactly the think you need.
Check this out:
https://api.jquery.com/clone/

```
// Original element with attached data
var $elem = $( "#elem" ).data( "arr", [ 1 ] ),
    $clone = $elem.clone( true )
      // Deep copy to prevent data sharing
      .data( "arr", $.extend( [], $elem.data( "arr" ) ) );
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need! Thank you!